# Filtering on Query Executed on LightSwitch not working

Tags: visual-studio-lightswitch

There is an entity with a Computed field on it. I'd like to filter based on this field. This can't be done in the PreprocessQuery method. However, the Executed method appears to be ideal to do such kind of filters, but, when I try to modify the IEnumerable result parameter of this method, the changes are not reflected on the screen.
Am I doing something wrong in this scenario?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't realized that the result parameter on this method is not passed by reference (as in Preprocess), and I was trying to modify it.
I'd like to know, though, what's the intended use of the Executed hook...

Answer (score 1):

I believe you could not filter the computed field.  But you can re-create the computed field at the pre-process method and then filter it from there.